# .net wrapper for native dll - how to minimize risk of run-time error?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, dll, wrapper

I am developing a C# application. Since I have some algorithms for least-squares fit in C/C++ that would be too cumbersome too translate, I have made the C++ code into a dll and then created a wrapper in C#.

In the C# code, I have defined a struct that is passed to the unmanaged C++ code as a pointer. The struct contains the initial guesstimates for the fitting functions, and it is also used to return the results of the fit.

It appears to me that you must define the struct in both the managed and the unmanaged code. However, someone using my source code in in the future might decide to change the fields of the struct in the C# application, without understanding that they also have to change the struct in the native code. This will result in a run-time error at best (and produce erroneous results at worse), but there will be no error message telling the developer / end user what is wrong.

From my understanding, it impossible to create a test in the unmanaged C++ DLL that checks if the struct contains the correct fields, but is it posible to have the DLL returning a struct of the correct format to the C# wrapper?

Otherwise, what ways are there to reduce the risk that some careless programmer in the future causes run-time errors that are hard to detect?

Sample code:

```
//C++
struct InputOutputStruct {
    double a,b,c;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DoSomethingToStruct(InputOutputStruct* s)
{
```

//  ... algorithm

```
}

//C#
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct InputOutputStruct {
        public double a,b,c;
    }

[DllImport("CpluplusDll.dll")]
    public static unsafe extern bool DoSomethingToStruct(InputOutputStruct* s);

class CSharpWrapper {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InputOutputStruct s = new InputOutputStruct();
        unsafe {
            InputOutpustruct* sPtr = &s;
            DoSomethingToStruct(sPtr);
            s = *sPtr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off-Topic: The size of bool differs from C++ ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897567/c-c-float-issues )

Comment: Thanks:) I have changed my code accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It appears to me that you must define the struct in both the managed
>   and the unmanaged code.

Not true. This is what C++/CLI was invented for- facilitate much easier interoperation with C++ and .NET.

Comment: Of course C++/CLI could be used, but maybe he is pinned to pure C/C++.

Comment: @Felix: There is nothing "C/C++" about it. He is using C++. There is no C here.

Comment: He says `C/C++` but this does not matter. Maybe the dll must be written in C/C++, thats something i wanted to point out. If he can use C++/CLI you answer is exactly what he needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I have some C code, however after reading a bit on this forum I came to conclusion that it was possible to rename the file to .cpp, in order to being able to compile with the /clr option. I realise it is not a very neat solution though.
The c file I am using is the least squares fit function here:
http://joachimwuttke.de/lmfit/index.html

Answer (score 1):

> but is it posible to have the DLL returning a struct of the correct format to the C# wrapper?

I don't think so, because you always need to define the structs on the C# side.

#### Here are a solution which may work ( never tested ):

- Give each struct which is shared a unique identifier on both sides ( GUID, Macros )
- Create a reflection for C++ which contains informations about the the types which are used on C# and C++ side. This could be done by using macros.
- Compare the C++ structs and the C# structs on startup by using the GUIDs, reflection and macros. You can also use `sizeof` to compare sizes first.

---

- That could be a lot of work
- When working on C++ side you still can make a lot of things wrong when you not know about the macros